# Using Linq to select a list of Entities, linked Entities, linked Entities

Tags: linq, list, entities, entityset

Apologies for the poor question title - I'm not sure how to describe what I'm doing but that is the best I could come up with, please edit it if what I'm asking for has a real name!

I have Programmes, which can have a group of Projects assigned, which in turn have groups of Outputs assigned.

I would like to get all the outputs for the Programme through it's projects as one big list of outputs. I have this:

```
From pp In Me.ProgrammeProjects Select pp.Project.Outputs
```

Which basically gets me a list of output lists. (An Ienumerable Of EntitySet Of Output).

I'm brute forcing my way through Linq and can't find any examples of this (or can't recognise one when I see it). How can I do this using just Linq rather than for loops and Linq where I'd go through each EntitySet and add it's contents to a bigger list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or go against the linq context directly:

```
from o in context.Outputs
where o.Project.ProgrammeProjects.ID = 1
select o
```

The reverse will work too and query straight from the data context's table.

Comment: I think this is the best option - I didn't think of going against Outputs directly - this is by far the easiest option - I just need to create a repository for Outputs... cheers Brian

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a list of outputs for a specific programme?

If so, try something like this:

```
var result = (from pp in ProgrammeProjects
where pp.Name.Equals("ProjectA")
select pp.Project.Outputs).ToList();
```

or

once you get your list of outputs, you could use a lambda expression to get a subset.

```
var result = (from pp in ProgrammeProjects
select pp.Project.Outputs).ToList();

var subResult = result.FindAll(target => target.OutputParameter.Equals("findThisValue");
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

If not, give a bit more detail of the data structure and what you're trying to retrieve and I'll do my best to help.

Patrick.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've left work now but this looks good, I will try it tomorrow and let you know, thanks

Comment: Hi Patrick, I tried your code and couldn't get what I wanted. Instead I've posted my solution - which isn't very good but should give you an idea of the final result I'm after. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I've resorted to doing it, but I can tell it's going to be slow when the amount of data increases.

```
    Dim allOutputs As New Generic.List(Of Output)

    Dim outputLists = From pp In Me.ProgrammeProjects Select pp.Project.Outputs.ToList

    For Each outputList In outputLists
        Dim os = From o In outputList Where o.OutputTypeID = Type Select o
        allOutputs.AddRange(os)
    Next

    Return allOutputs
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a bit confused as to what kind of data you're trying to retrieve. Here is what I understand.

1. You have a list of Programmes
2. Each Programme can have many Projects
3. Each Project can have many outputs.

Goal: To find all outputs of a certain type. Is this right?

It doesn't look like you're retrieving any data related to the project or programme so 
something like this should work:

```
   Dim allOutputs As Generic.List(Of Outputs) = (From output In Me.Outputs Where output.OutputType.Equals(Type) Select output).ToList()
```

Let me know how it goes.

Patrick.

Comment: Hi Patrick, your right in that I want a list of outputs of a type but I don't have a list of outputs to select from. I have a list of lists. I want to merge all the lists into a single one. The for loopin my answer is how I've done it but I thought Linq would have a better way. Cheers